# Does changing the condition for a while loop in Python immediately end the loop?

Tags: python

I am working on a program for Pig the Dice game, a project on Rosetta Code. I ran into a problem and have broken the program even more than I imagined possible. Every couple of years I toy around with Python a bit, but I barely have any understanding of programming at all, so I figured this project could help with that. I'm running into a problem with my code and I think it may be related to this function:

```
def play(ps, s):
    global turn
    turn_score = 0
    while turn == True:
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Current turn: " + str(turn_score) + "\nPlayer: " + str(ps) + "\nAI: " + str(s))
        choice = input("\n\nRoll[R] or Hold[H]?\n\n")
        choice = choice.lower()
        if choice == "r":
            current_score = roll()
            
            if current_score == 0 or current_score is None:
                turn_score = 0
                turn = False
                return ps
            else:
                turn_score += current_score
        elif choice == "h":
            ps += turn_score
            turn = False
            return ps
```

In that loop does ps ever actually get returned? The problem I'm running into is that this function is returning as NoneType instead of an integer. As I said, I don't really know what I'm doing so I hope this makes sense. I'll post the whole thing here, in case it helps.(I'm sure there's more problems)

```
#goal is to get 100
#you can roll 2-6 and choose to roll again or hold
#1 is no points and turn is over 
import random
die = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


def roll():
    global turn
    roll = random.choice(die)
    print("\nRoll is: " + str(roll) + "\n\n")
    score = 0
    
    if roll == 1:
        score = 0
        print("\nOof!")
    else:
        score += roll
        return score


def play(ps, s):
    global turn
    turn_score = 0
    while turn == True:
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Current turn: " + str(turn_score) + "\nPlayer: " + str(ps) + "\nAI: " + str(s))
        choice = input("\n\nRoll[R] or Hold[H]?\n\n")
        choice = choice.lower()
        if choice == "r":
            current_score = roll()
            
            if current_score == 0 or current_score is None:
                turn_score = 0
                turn = False
                return ps
            else:
                turn_score += current_score
        elif choice == "h":
            ps += turn_score
            turn = False
            return ps


def ai_play(s, ps):
    global turn
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("\n \n AI's Turn")
    tick = 10
    turnscore = 0
    while tick > 0:
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Current turn: "  + str(turnscore) + "\nAI: " + str(s) + "\nPlayer: " + str(ps))
        curTick = tick / 5
##        print("\n\n\nTICK: " + str(tick) + "\n C. TICK: " + str(curTick))

        ran = random.uniform(0, 2)
        if ran <= curTick:
            roll = random.choice(die)
            print('Hit!')
            print(str(roll) + "\n\n")
            tick -= 1

            if roll == 1:
                turnscore = 0
                turn = True
                return s
            elif roll > 1:
                turnscore += roll
        else:
            print('Stay!')
            s += turnscore
            turn = True
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("Your Turn!")
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
            return s
        

        
pScore = 0
score = 0

def game():
    global on
    global score
    global pScore
    print("Welcome to: PIG THE DICE!\n\n")
    if pScore > 100:
        print("You Win! " + str(pScore) + "\nAI got: " + str(score))
        on = False
    if pScore > 100:
        print("You Lose! " + str(pScore) + "\nAI got: " + str(score))
        on = False
        
    while on == True:
        if turn == True:
            if play(pScore, score) is None or play(pScore, score) == 0:
                print("\n\n")
            else:
                pScore = play(pScore, score)
        else:
            if ai_play(score, pScore) is None or ai_play(score, pScore) == 0:
                print("\n\n")
            else:
                score = ai_play(score, pScore)
    
on = True
turn = True

game()
```

Edit: I would like to add that I sort of code as I go, so you can see multiple ways I've tried to fix the problem

Comment: FYI, `while x:` is the same as `while x == True:` and is considered best practice.

Comment: The error occurs here:- *ps += turn_score* because ps is None